# Nginx rewrite arguments

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, nginx, request-uri

I use Nginx with my webserver, and don't fully understand how the rewrite works here. I got it working on Apache.

I use MVC based PHP project, and i want to use clean URL's as i have done with Apache.

`www.domain.com/index.php?url=home/index` works fine.
`www.domain.com/home/index` does not work.
As you can see, i want to have clean URL's like the last one.

I've tried several rewrites, and don't know if I should use try_files or rewrite. But I guess it's rewrite im after.

As I said, I'm still learning the rewrite.
My server block looks like this:

```
server {

listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /usr/share/nginx/html/pub/;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name localhost;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/index.php?$arg_url /$arg_url permanent;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

}
```

I thought my rewrite block made sense, but I guess it doesn't. Tried several rewrites, either I get 500 or 404 error. And as I said, I don't get rewrites yet. Need some help to get started.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an expert with nginx either but I think you are looking for something like this:

```
location / {                                                            
 index  index.html index.htm index.php;
 if (!-d $request_filename) {
  rewrite  ^/(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1  last;
  break;                                                  
 }
}
```

Then you can remove that rewrite directive

The rest of my config looks like this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
 root /var/www/path;
 fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
 #try_files $uri=404;
 fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
 fastcgi_index index.php;
 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name

 include fastcgi_params;
 fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
 fastcgi_buffers 2564k;
 fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
 fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;

}
location ~ /\.git {
 denyall;
}

#Staticfileslocation

location ~* ^.+.(swf|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|bmp|js|zip)$ {
 expires max;
 root /var/www/path;
}
```

Comment: That works like a charm as I can see. I almost, but just almost, had the same rewrite before, but I did not have the `if(!-d ...)` statement. Thank you! This solved it. What is the .git directive for?

Comment: The .git is only useful if you use git to deploy just remove it otherwise. I have this because i copied that config from a sandbox server that i just pull code from my github repo

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
server {

listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /usr/share/nginx/html/pub/;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name localhost;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

}
```

Comment: I tested this as well, but when I use this, my resources (CSS, JS, IMG) are not loaded for some reason. But I got it working with the code @Irossy posted. Thank you though.